# Having Troubling Filtering Records Down Using Data Statements in PROC SQL & Teradata

Tags: sql, date, sas, teradata

Within proc sql I wish to filter my results via date ranges, and I keep getting errors. My date variables are DATE8 & the format is 04JUL1776.

I tried adding some inputs around the specific dates in the code. That did not yield anything.;

```
proc sql noprint;
%tdconnectTo;
create table ptemp.DL2_2018_IDS as
select * from connection to Teradata (
select     distinct
           PERS_ID
     , REC_EFF_DT
     , REC_TERM_DT
from       oeauacbrgdlp1.DV_DIM_MBR
where      PERS_ID is not null
and        REC_EFF_DT <= '31DEC2018'd and REC_TERM_DT >= '01JAN2018'd
order by PERS_ID
);
disconnect from teradata;
quit;
```

Comment: Proc SQL is SAS, yes?  If so, you should probably add that tag. And what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pass-through SQL, then you need to supply the values in a form acceptable to the database. For a SQL date literal:

```
REC_EFF_DT <= date'2018-12-31' and REC_TERM_DT >= date'2018-01-01'
```

or if you really need to supply a string value in SAS DATE9 form for some reason, you should explicitly tell the database to convert that string to a date:

```
REC_EFF_DT <= to_date('31DEC2018','DDMONYYYY') and REC_TERM_DT >= to_date('01JAN2018','DDMONYYYY')
```

or

```
REC_EFF_DT <= CAST('31DEC2018' AS DATE FORMAT'DDMMMYYYY') and REC_TERM_DT >= CAST('01JAN2018' AS DATE FORMAT'DDMMMYYYY')
```